# Azure Language services is trying to create roles and I don't have the permission to do so

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services

I am trying to deploy Azure Language Service (Custom text classification). However I cannot create the resource that I want because the service is trying to assign roles. The reason for this is that it has access to the storage account. Obviously I do not have the permissions to do so because I work for a company. Is there some way to circumvent this? Is there a way to create the resource without needing the permission of assigning roles?

As a side note: I do have the permission to create the resource to begin with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options to use Custom text classification on Azure Language Service:

1. use a newly created Azure Language Service resource and select "Custom text classification" during the setup of this resource
2. use an existing Azure Language Service resource and enable "Custom text classification" on it (2 steps setup)

In both cases, you will need the intervention of someone who can setup roles on resources, but the 2nd option needs less actions on their side (it's just role assignment versus resources creation for 1st option).

## 1 step resource setup

In the 1st case (I guess the one you did), the process needs to setup the roles as you mentioned, and you are blocked as you don't have this permission.

## 2 steps setup

### Procedure

In the 2nd case, you could:

- first create the Azure Language Service without selecting "Custom text classification" (see details below)
- enable managed-identity on this resource
- then create a Storage Account for later use with it
- ask the admin to set the permissions on your storage
- turn on "Custom text classification" on your Azure Language resource

### Azure Language Service resource setup

#### Create resource

- Don't select "Custom text classification" feature during creation
- Region: "West US 2" or "West Europe"
- Pricing: "Standard S"

#### Enable managed-identity

In Azure Portal, under "Identity" tab, turn on managed identity (whether System Assigned or User Assigned, up to you)
[image: enable managed identity]

After clicking "On" and saving:
[image: managed identity enabled]

### Storage account setup

#### Create resource

Create your storage in the same region as your Language Service resource:
[image: Storage account creation]

#### Setup permissions

Permissions are details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/language-service/custom-classification/how-to/create-project?tabs=portal&WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003365#roles-for-your-storage-account) in the documentation

> Your Azure blob storage account must have the below roles:
>
> - Your resource has the owner or contributor role on the storage account.
> - Your resource has the Storage blob data owner or Storage blob data contributor role on the storage account.
> - Your resource has the Reader role on the storage account.

So you have to ask your "administrator" to go to the Storage account resource, "Access Control (IAM)" section, and add the roles to your previously enabled managed identity. By using the least privilege principle I would set the following roles:

- Storage blob data contributor
- Reader

Example for Storage Blob Data Contributor setup:
[image]

### Finalize Azure Language Service setup

Go to Language Studio (https://language.cognitive.azure.com/) and choose your language service resource. Then, go to "Custom text classification".
[image]

Click "Create new project" and you will be guided to link your language service resource to your storage account:
[image]

Select the Storage account and click next.

You can check in the "Activity Log" of your Language Service resource that it linked the Storage to this resource:
[image]

It added the "userOwnedStorage" property to the properties:
[image]

Then you're good to go!

Comment: Thank you for you detailed answer. Didn't really solve the problem of being unable to assign roles but I got the permissions and was finally able to create the resource today!

Comment: There was no way to solve the permissions problem ;)

Comment: I thought so. It was worth the try. Thank you :)